# Database name in Source control

Tags: database, version-control

We're developing an aspx project with Visual Studio 2010 Professional, SQL Server 2008 R2 and Team Foundation Server 2010.  Since the development is being carried out in multiple offices, each developer has their own local instances of the databases.
I want to bring these multiple databases under source control (or at least the schemas of the DB, structure and stored procedures - data doesn't matter to me).  My preferred approach is to add database projects to the VS solution, which is already source controlled in TFS.  Any changes will be distributed by TFS, and can be deployed locally.

The problem I'm having is that the database projects contain a reference to a local database instance (server & name).  When someone gets the latest version of my changes, they will have a reference to my local DB instance (which is different to their local DB instance).  They would need to change the DB details (thus checking the dbproj out) in order to get my updates.

So, is there any way that the database server & name can be left out of source control while the schemas remain under source control?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can. However, you could use an alias, so all of the developers use a database on their local machine, but referenced by the same alias.

Take a look at: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/ for how to set an alias up.

That way you can separate the database from the connection details.

Comment: That looks like it's going to work perfectly!  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm involved in developing a unique enforced [database source control](http://www2.dbmaestro.com/l/11742/2014-06-12/w4ck1) solution called DBmaestro TeamWork.

It has a plugin to SSMS which allows the developer to work directly on the database objects (change their working environment), run their tests and then perform Check-In which reads the metadata (tables' structure, procedures, functions, views etc.) to the version control repository.

With the Impact Analysis it is easy to merge changes from different databases to a single database.
The impact analysis algorithm perform 3-way analysis (not just a simple compare & sync) to identify changes origin from developerA which should not be reverted when developer merge his changes and it ignores the database name when running the impact analysis or generating the delta script.

Comment: Please take a look at: [Help Center > Our model](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)